# Is there a solution for poor Acer Iconia A500 playback of MP4 video?

Tags: video, acer-iconia-a500, mp4

When playing back MP4 video files my Acer Iconia A500 will drop frames and produce video artifacts. Does it just not support MP4, or is there a better MP4 player I can download?

**Update**: Turns out it was just an issue with 1080p video. 720p video plays back great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the file being of type mp4 and everything to do with the video codec being used. If you have video files that are not playing  particularly well on the tablet, you should consider looking at [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), a free piece of software that allows you to convert video formats. In-depth  instructions are available at  [How to: Handbrake and A500](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1184002) on xda-developers.

Basically, you want to use the following settings in the application:

1. Load your video in Handbrake
2. Picture tab - set Anamorphic to Loose and Width to 1280
3. Video tab - Select Constant Quality with a value of 20
4. Audio tab - Audio Codec AAC(faac), Mixdown Dolby Pro Logic II, Samplerate Auto, Bitrate 160, DRC 0.0

There are some settings that can be tweaked in the Advance tab (see the forum post I linked). You can then save this profile in Handbrake and run this for any video files you encounter.

For playback on the Iconia, I use Mobo Player but there are others that work fine.

Comment: I'll try that. I've found 720p (and lower) works fine, but 1080p is where it gets flaky.

Comment: The display on the Acer is only 720p so the only reason to go higher is for HDMI output.

Comment: Hmmm . . Good point. I wonder if that is the cause of my sorrows. I shall try some more 720p videos and see how they fly.

Answer (score 4):

You could give a try to a pre-alpha version of [VLC](http://cvpcs.org/blog/2011-09-18/videolan_for_android_pre-alpha). Be warned this is not a finalized application and there might be errors, but it's still worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [MX Video Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) with the [MX Video Player CODEC (ARMv7)](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mxtech.ffmpeg.v7_vfpv3d16&hl=en)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the first part of your answer. For the question better MP4 player I'd suggest you [Mobo Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil) and [Rock Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.redirectin.rockplayer.android.unified.lite).

Comment: Tried both, and they are nicer players, but they don't help with the playback.